# When my Android program compiles but the emulator gives me the error of "Stopped Unexpectedly"

Tags: android, android-emulator

Why does that happen?  The program I am dealing with compiled (meaning no syntax errors)

but it crashed in the emulator.

What are the usual situations where something like that happen?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you post some code we could try to help you better...

Answer (score 2):

Your application is syntactically correct, but that doesn't mean that it's correct!!
Probably your application is trying to access a resource with the wrong name or not created yet.
Use log and/or toast to debug your app and try to understand the part or line that causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added your starting activity to the Manifest.